# Reference as a non-type template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

The example below attempts to use a variable of reference type as an argument for a non-type template parameter (itself of reference type). Clang, GCC and VC++ all reject it. But why? I can't seem to find anything in the standard that makes it illegal.

```
int obj = 42;
int& ref = obj;

template <int& param> class X {};

int main()
{
    X<obj> x1;  // OK
    X<ref> x2;  // error
}
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/ENIQS47115)

---

CLang says:

> source_file.cpp:9:7: error: non-type template argument of reference type 'int &' is not an object

Others complain in similar ways.

---

From the standard (all quotes from C++11; C++14 doesn't appear to have significant changes in relevant parts):

> **14.3.2/1** A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> ...
>
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage ... expressed (ignoring parentheses) as `&` *id-expression*, except that the `&` ... shall be omitted if the corresponding *template-parameter* is a reference
>
> ...

Now what's a constant expression:

> **5.19/2** A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless it involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression (3.2)...
>
> ...
>
> - an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression
>
> ...

---

As far as I can tell, `ref` in `X<ref>` is an *id-expression* that refers to a variable of reference type. This variable has a preceding initialization, initialized with the expression `obj`. I believe `obj` is a constant expression, and anyway if it isn't, then `X<obj>` shouldn't compile either.

- So what am I missing?
- Which clause in the standard renders `X<ref>` invalid, while `X<obj>` is valid?

Comment: A similar issue occurs for `int x = 0; constexpr int& r = x; template <int* param> class X {}; X<&r>{};` As far as I can tell, the compilers reject these cases because they "don't follow" what an expression is referring to. I suspect they're directly using the mangled name appearing in the *id-expression* to create a name (for linkage purposes) for the (class) template specialization (or the Standard intends to allow such a simple implementation).

Comment: @dyp Check out [n4198](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html).

Comment: @remyabel Thanks, I have already linked to [N4268](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html) in my related question about pointers (see -->)

Comment: `g++` actually gives a sensible explanation to the issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Introduction

It is correct saying that the name of a *reference* is an *id-expression*, though; the *id-expression* doesn't refer to whatever the reference is referencing, but the reference itself.

```
 int    a = 0;
 int& ref = a; // "ref" is an id-expression, referring to `ref` - not `a`
```

---

#### The Standard ([N4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf))

You are quoting the relevant sections of the standard in your post, but you left out the most important part (emphasize mine):

> 14.3.2p1 **Template non-type arguments** [temp.arg.nontype]
>
> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> - <sub>...</sub>
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of a complete object with static sturage duration and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates and function
>   *template-ids* but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as `&` *id-expression*, **where *id-expression* is the name of an object or function**, except that the `&` may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding *template-parameter* is a reference; <sub>...</sub>

<sup>**Note:** In earlier drafts *"where id-expression is the name of an object or function"* isn't present; it was addressed by [DR 1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1570) - which undoubtedly makes the intent more clear.</sup>

---

#### A variable of *reference type* is not an *object*?

You are absolutely correct; the reference itself has reference type, and can merely act as an object when part of an expression.

> 5p5 **Expressions** [expr]
>
> If an expression initially has the type "reference to `T`" (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

---

#### Elaboration

It is very important to note that the *constant expression* (*"that designates the address of a complete object..."*) must be one of `&id-expression`, or `id-expression`.

Even though a *constant-expression*, that isn't just an *id-expression*, might refer to an object with static storage duration, we cannot use it to *"initialize"* a *template-parameter* of *reference-* or *pointer type*.

<sub>**Example Snippet**</sub>

```
template<int&>
struct A { };

int            a = 0;
constexpr int& b = (0, a); // ok, constant-expression
A<(0, a)>      c = {};     // ill-formed, `(0, a)` is not an id-expression
```

<sup>**Note**: This is also a reason behind the fact that we cannot use *string-literals* as *template-arguments*; they are not *id-expressions*.</sup>

Comment: My copy of C++11 (the final draft, forgot the exact N-number) doesn't say "where id-expression is the name of an object or function". C++14 (N3936) does; I missed that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I will update my answer to reflect that it's not present in C++11, though the meaning is the same in previous standards; it still uses `id-expression`.

Comment: I disagree that a reference doesn't denote the address of an object. See [DR 1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1570) (which added the wording in question). If your claim were true, no change would have been necessary and DR 1570 would be NAD. I'd say failure to prohibit `X<ref>` is a defect in C++11, corrected in C++14.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik a *"revised"* wording does not mean that the intent is not there, it merely means that it should be more precise - that's my take; do you have any proposal on how to make the wording of my answer any clearer (more accurate)?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik See the updated (edited) answer, instead of trying to clearify things myself I took the liberty of adding a link to the relevant *DR*. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 2 questions: 
1) Why is the standard written the way that forbids using refernce as a non-type argument? I thought that, for all intents and purposes, a reference is the same as an object it references. Apparently here it's not, but why?
2) Is there a way to still use a reference and not an original object as a template argument? I wrote the template, so I can change its argument to, e.g. a pointer.