# Is it a defect about a non-type template parameter of a reference type that there are no special rules permit it to be used in a constant expression

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider this example:

```cpp
template<int const& rf>
struct A{
  void fun(){
    constexpr int v = rf;  //#1
  }
};
int const object = 0;
int main(){
   A<object> a;
   a.fun();
}
```

GCC and Clang both [agree](https://godbolt.org/z/xeq38e) that `rf` can be used as a constant expression.

However, in this case, `rf` is an id-expression. Hence, only the id-expression satisfies the following rule can it be used in a constant expression. The relevant rule is:
[[expr.const#5.12]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.12)

> an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference **has a preceding initialization** and either
>
> > - it is usable in constant expressions or
> > - its lifetime began within the evaluation of E;

For the id-expression `rf` at `#1`, its lifetime does not begin within the evaluation of initialization. So, bullet 2 is not satisfied here.  At the view of the declaration `constexpr int v = rf;` where id-expression `rf` does not have a **preceding initialization**. For bullet 1, the relevant rule says:

> A **constant-initialized** potentially-constant variable V is usable in constant expressions at a point P if **V's initializing declaration D is reachable from P** and
>
> > - V is constexpr
> > - V is not initialized to a TU-local value, or
> > - P is in the same translation unit as D.

`rf` is not constant-initialized since it neither has an initializer nor its default-initialization results in some initialization being performed.  So, the id-expression `rf` used in `#1` will violate [expr.const#5.12]. Hence, it cannot be used in `#1`. Actually, all compilers agree `rf` can be used in constant-expression(it also conforms to intuitive). However, the rule in the standard conflicts here. How to interpret this? Does it lack wording for a non-type template parameter that can be used in a constant expression?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference as a non-type template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662784/reference-as-a-non-type-template-argument)

Comment: @dfri It's a subtle difference, in that question `X<ref> x2;` obviously ill-formed because of the id-expression's lifetime began before that and the standard explicitly said that. In my question, this point is similar to that, but it's considered to be well-formed by compilers.

Comment: I was thinking about the `constexpr int& b` in the answer of the linked question: `A<b> a{};` is well-formed, and afaics `b` in that context is similar to `B` in yours. I think the essential part is covered in the linked question: a variable of reference type is not an object; your part 2 examples contains objects, not only (constant expression) lvalue references.

Comment: @dfri It's quite different with that. `constexpr int& b` is well-formed, because at that context, the `a` is a glvalue constant-expression which has static storage duration. I have modified my question to make it more easy to understand. The issue is that at `#1`, the id-expression of reference type would ill-formed according to the rule, but actually it's considered to be well-formed  by compilers

Comment: @dfri In that question , `A<b> a{};` is well-formed, because firstly, `b` is an id-expression  of reference type and has a preceding initialization , secondly, `it is initialized with a constant expression`, namely `a`, so it satisfied this rule, hence `A<b> a{};` is well-formed since `b` is a glvalue constant-expression. This is all answers in that question but not here

Comment: Ok, look forward to some answer/feedback from some language lawyer guru!

Comment: @dfri The difference here is that, at point `#1`, `B` has no preceding initialization and it's lifetime has started but not within a evaluation of `#1`.

Comment: @dfri Yes, I'm looking for these knowledge men. Please vote this question to make someone notice this question. In addition, I 70% sure this maybe a defect :-)

Comment: "An expression e is a core constant expression unless the **evaluation** of e...",  and look in [dcl.init.ref]/5 "The usual **lvalue-to-rvalue**, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer standard conversions are not needed, and therefore are suppressed, when such direct bindings to lvalues are done." lvalue-to-rvalue is what is usualy refered as the **evaluation**. The term is defined here:http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.execution-7. In the GCC documentation you may read that there the hole in the standard here: what is an evaluation. But it is accepted as is.

Comment: Direct binding is not considered an evaluation, rather reference constexprness are governed by:http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#11.sentence-2. And if you want to understand it, hopefully you will consider a commity member someone knowledge and you should read its blog post: https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/02/05/constexpr-array-size/

Comment: And the standard you cite is too hold considering: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.12.1, they are constantly fixing this part since at least 10 years.

Comment: @Oliv  No, to determine the identity of an object, the glvalue evaluation is used to do this. It's irrelevant whether the reference is directly binding or not. And part 2 prove that.

Comment: Not sure if non-type template parameter is a variable (ofc it is not a data member)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  [Reference](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#4.3) should be, the others all prvalue.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer This outcome prove that non-type `Reference` parameter is a variable.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I don't know whether template parameters are considered variables, but I think they should probably be defined not to be, since they don't have properties like lifetime and storage duration that variables are supposed to have. Worth opening up a core issue about IMHO.

Comment: @BrianBi storage duration and lifetime are properties of objects and references. Not variables. Variables' properties are: scope, linkage etc.